# Azure Service Bus - Session Processor vs Session Receiver Client?

Tags: azureservicebus

I've been trying to find some guidance on the functional difference between `ServiceBusProcessorClient` and `ServiceBusSessionReceiverAsyncClient`.

From [Azure SDK samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/azure-messaging-servicebus/src/samples/java/com/azure/messaging/servicebus/ServiceBusSessionProcessorSample.java) it seems that **ProcessorClient** is easier to implement, and it's still asynchronous.

Documentation doesn't seem to cover this.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: My tip, ask ChatGPT ...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continuously receive messages, one has to build a message pump. The SDK team has provided a default message pump that covers most of the scenarios but not all. For scenarios not covered by the default implementation or when customizations are required, `ServiceBusSessionReceiver` is a lower-level client that can be used to build the necessary functionality.